# Tensor product of two torsion free elements.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules. If $m\in M, n\in N$ and $Ann(m) = 0, Ann(n) = 0$, whether $m\otimes n$ in $M\otimes N$ equal zero or not?

After discussing with others, I know:

(1)This is true if $R$ is a domain. In fact, $M\otimes_R N \otimes_R Frac(R) \cong S^{-1}M \otimes_{S^{-1}R} \otimes S^{-1}N,S=R- \{ 0\}$,and $m$ and $n$ are non-zero in $S^{-1}M$ and $S^{-1}N$ respectively. Hence, $m/1 \otimes_{S^{-1}R} n/1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow m\otimes_R n \neq 0 \ $in$ \ M\otimes_R N$.

(2)If $R$ is reduced, then for every minimal prime ideal, $R_p$ is a field, it is to say that $\forall r\in p,\exists r_1\in R-p$ such that $r_1r =0$. Then $M\otimes_R N \otimes_R R/p \cong M/pM \otimes_{R/p} N/pN$. If $m\otimes_R n =0 \ in \ M\otimes_R N$,then $\bar{m}\otimes_{R/p} \bar{n} $ in $ M/pM \otimes_{R/p} N/pN$, it contradicts to (1).

Now we need to deal with a detail: $\bar{m}$ and $\bar{n}$ are torsionfree in $M/pM$ and $N/pN$ respectively, particularly, $\bar{m} \neq 0$ and $\bar{n} \neq 0$.
If $\bar{m}$ is torsion,  there exists $r\in R-p$ such  that $rm = \sum_{i=1}^{s}r_im_i, r_i\in p,m_i \in M$. And we can choose $t_i \in R-p,1\leq i\leq s$ such that $t_ir_i=0$, therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{s}t_i r m=0 \ in \ R$  and $\sum_{i=1}^{s}t_i r \notin p\ i.e \ \bar{\sum_{i=1}^{s}t_i r} \neq 0 \ in \ R/p$. So $\bar{m}$ is torsionfree. Similarly, $\bar{n}$ is torsionfree.

Dose this question true if $R$ is not reduced? I think it maybe not ture but I can find a counterexample.

Comment: It is different from my question. My question is that whether $m\otimes_R n$ in $M\otimes_R N$ equals to 0 or not. It is not equal to 0 in $Rm\otimes_R Rn$, but maybe equal to 0 in $M\otimes_R N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I know how to solve the case $R$ is not reduced.

If $m\otimes_R n =0$ in $M\otimes_R N$, then $\bar{m}\otimes_{R/Nil(R)}\bar{n} = 0$ in $M/Nil(R)M \otimes_{R/Nil(R)} N/Nil(R)N$.It is enough to prove that $\bar{m}$ and $\bar{n}$ are torsion free in $M/Nil(R)M$ and $N/Nil(R)N$ respectively.

If there exists $s\in R-Nil(R)$ such that $sm \in Nil(R)M$, then $\frac{m}{1}\in R_s$(localization at point $s$) is nonzero and torsion free. $sm \in Nil(R)M$ implies $sm = \sum_{i=1}^{n}r_im_i, r_i \in Nil(R),m_i\in M$,then $\frac{m}{1} = \frac{sm}{s} \in Nil(R_s)M_s$. Hence $Ann(\frac{m}{1})\neq 0$ since $\exists t\in \mathbb{N}_{>1}, (\frac{r_1}{1},\cdots,\frac{r_n}{1})^{t}=0, (\frac{r_1}{1},\cdots,\frac{r_n}{1})^{t-1}\neq 0$, a contradiction!

In summary, the question I asked above is true.

Comment: For $\frac{m}{1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{r_i}{1} \frac{m_i}{s}$ ,where $r_i \in Nil(R)$ , and $(\frac{r_1}{1},\cdots ,\frac{r_n}{1})^t =0 ,(\frac{r_1}{1},\cdots ,\frac{r_n}{1})^{t-1} \neq 0 $, then there exists a nonzero element $x\in (\frac{r_1}{1},\cdots ,\frac{r_n}{1})^{t-1} $ such that $x \frac{m}{1} = 0$.    And I fixed some writing errors, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee $t > 1$, although it doesn't really matter, since $t = 1$ iff $s^Nr_i = 0$ for some $N$ and all $i$, in which case $\frac{m}{1} = \frac{s^Nsm}{s^{N+1}} = 0$

Comment: A few more typos: you wrote "$\frac{m}{1} \in R_s$", and also have a weird "$= \in$" sign